# How to obtain an unformatted string representation of an NSDecimal or NSDecimalNumber?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, string

I have an NSDecimal and need this as technical string, i.e. with no formatting in any way. Floating point should be a "." if there is any, and minus sign should just be a "-" if there is any. besides that, there should be no formatting going on like grouping or chinese numbers.

I was looking for 2 hours through the SDK but it seems there is nothing simple to accomplish this. Are there solutions for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For NSDecimal, you can use NSDecimalString with a specified locale:

```
NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
NSString *decimalString =  NSDecimalString(&decimalValue, usLocale);
[usLocale release];
```

The U.S. locale uses a period for the decimal separator, and no thousands separator, so I believe that will get you the kind of formatting you're looking for.

As others have pointed out, for an NSDecimalNumber you can use the -descriptionWithLocale: method with the above-specified U.S. locale.  This doesn't lose you any precision.

Answer (score 4):

### [NSDecimalNumber](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
NSLog(@"%@", [theNumber stringValue]);
```

### [NSDecimal](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSDecimal)

```
NSLog(@"%@", NSDecimalString(&theDecimal, nil));
```

Comment: +1 for showing that we don't need to supply a locale... there is so much cruft in Obj C string handling (IMHO)

Answer (score 3):

`NSDecimalNumber` is a subclass of [`NSNumber`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) which has the `-stringValue` method.

> ### stringValue
>
> Returns the receiver’s
>   value as a human-readable string.
>
> ```
> - (NSString *)stringValue
> ```
>
> #### Return Value
>
> The receiver’s value as a
>   human-readable string, created by
>   invoking `descriptionWithLocale:` where
>   locale is `nil`.
>
> ### descriptionWithLocale:
>
> Returns a string that represents the contents of
>   the receiver for a given locale.
>
> ```
> - (NSString *)descriptionWithLocale:(id)aLocale
> ```
>
> #### Parameters aLocale
>
> An object
>   containing locale information with
>   which to format the description. Use
>   `nil` if you don’t want the description
>   formatted.

Just call `[theNumber stringValue]`.

Comment: That does not work. -descriptionWithLocale will destroy the value because it converts to double. double has less precision than an NSDecimal.

Comment: NSDecimalNumber has it's own descriptionWithLocale method, it does not rely on NSNumber.

Comment: Why would you think that? This example shows that `NSDecimalNumber` _isn't_ converted to a double when invoking `-stringValue`: http://pastebin.com/m7d720b57

Comment: @zaph: That's true. But `-stringValue` calls `-descriptionWithLocale` on `NSDecimalNumber`. Hence, my answer is the exact same as yours with a nicer method name.

Answer (score 0):

Use decimalNumberWithString from the NSDecimalNumber class:

```
NSDecimalNumber *dn = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:12345
                                                        exponent:-100
                                                      isNegative:YES];
NSDictionary *local = nil;
NSString *ds = [dn descriptionWithLocale: local];
NSLog(@"dn: %@", dn);
NSLog(@"ds: %@", ds);

dn: -0.00000000000000000000000 … 0000000000000000000000000000000000012345
ds: -0.00000000000000000000000 … 0000000000000000000000000000000000012345
```

Comment: `NSLog(@"dn: %@", dn);` just calls `[dn stringValue]`.