# Prevent scientific notation with NSDecimalNumber output as NSString

Tags: objective-c, c, gnustep, nsdecimalnumber

I have a problem similar to the one in this question: [How to obtain an unformatted string representation of an NSDecimal or NSDecimalNumber?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815664/how-to-obtain-an-unformatted-string-representation-of-an-nsdecimal-or-nsdecimaln) I need to have a number in string format accurately represented as an NSNumber, but this number is converted back to a string in other places, and I can't avoid that. The problem I'm having is that when the number is converted back to a string, the string is in scientific notation in some cases.

```
NSDecimalNumber *dn = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0.0001"];
NSString *s = [dn stringValue]; // s will be @"1E-4"
```

*How can I prevent this number from being displayed in scientific notation?*

I am working in a circa 2005 version of GNUstep (possibly v1.11.1 for GNUstep Base), rather than on mac or iPhone, which may account for some of the differences in behavior vs the other question I referenced. I have looked over the [base library API](http://www.gnustep.org/resources/documentation/Developer/Base/Reference/index.html) and the documentation in my own GNUstep install, but I can't seem to find anything to help.

**EDIT 2/7/12:**

The question has changed slightly, but the goal is still the same. Originally, I didn't think I was able to control the string output piece, but I can pass the value back as a string. At this point I am attempting to use a formatting string, but I still want to prevent the scientific notation from appearing.

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.14g", [val doubleValue]]
```

I've chosen to use `%g` because we would like a specific number of significant digits for the value. If I use `%f`, I can trim the extra zeros, but the number does not always come out cleanly. 800000000.79 appears as 800000000.7899999600, for example.

*Is there a way to get a cleanly formatted number with up to a certain number of significant digits (or decimal places) **without** displaying scientific notation before that number of digits?*

I'm willing to accept C advice as well.

Answer (score 2):

You should check out the [NSNumberFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
// Create formatter 
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];     
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle]; // adjust this
NSString *formattedOutput = [formatter stringFromNumber:yourDecimalNumber];
```

Comment: It looks like in whatever version of GNUstep we're using (1.11.1 maybe?), the NSNumberFormatter class isn't fully implemented. The docs contain this message: "This class is currently not implemented in GNUstep! All set methods will work, but stringForObject: will ignore the format completely. The documentation below describes what the behavior SHOULD be..."

Answer (score 1):

How about getting the the C value (double, int, long, etc.) and then format it as a C string, or as an `NSString` with `stringWithFormat:`?

Answer (score 0):

Try printing the number using NSNumberFormatter instead of the stringValue method. It has a lot more options.

(I'm assuming NSNumberFormatter is available on GNUstep)

Answer (score 0):

Use the below methods to avoid scientific exponent notation representation.

Convert Double to String

```
func getStringFrom(double doubleVal: Double) -> String
{
    var stringValue : String = "0.00"

    let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    formatter.usesSignificantDigits = true;
    formatter.maximumSignificantDigits = 100
    formatter.groupingSeparator = "";
    formatter.numberStyle = .DecimalStyle
    stringValue = formatter.stringFromNumber(doubleVal)!;

    return stringValue
```

}

Convert String to Double

```
func getDoubleFrom(textField textField: UITextField) -> Double
{
    var doubleValue : Double = 0.0

    if let val = textField.text
    {
        let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle
        let finalNumber = numberFormatter.numberFromString(val)
        doubleValue = (finalNumber?.doubleValue)!;
    }

    return doubleValue
}
```